# SPAZ to connect to Laconica

Tags: laconica

I installed a local version of Laconica microblogging in my env.  Then I downlowaded SPAZ (an AIR client) to try and talk to the Laconica app.  I get an authenitcation error.  I have put in the appropriate credentials - I think :)
But I think that I have to alter the API and base URL for connecting.
Ayone have any thoughts on how to make these two apps talk ?
Thanks in advance,

Linley

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get SPAZ and WITTY connected to a local copy of Laconica.  The trick was to  use the explicit API URL - http:///laconica/index.php/api/

Good luck to all.

LA